# Jade Template not Rendering Checkbox in IE

Tags: html, input, internet-explorer-9, pug

I'm attempting to implement a search bar template in client-side Jade template.

```
table.SearchBar(cellpadding="0", cellspacing="0")
    tr
        td.SearchCell
            div.SearchIndicator(id="SearchIndicator_#{eId}")
            input.SearchText.Initializing(id="SearchText_#{eId}", type="text", placeholder="gathering contacts list...")
        -if(parentName === "Contacts")
            td.SearchCell(style="width: 100px;")
                button.PresenceButton(id="PresenceButton_#{eId}")
                    input.PresenceCheckbox(type="checkbox", name="Presence", id="PresenceCheckbox_#{eId}")
                    p.PresenceLabel online only?
```

In Chrome && Firefox, everything renders fine. In IE 9, ONLY the checkbox fails to render at all, doesn't appear in the web inspector, and its absence also causes an error later in the script.

This is killing me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh... You can't put an **INPUT** element inside a **BUTTON** element in Internet Explorer.

Comment: And you shouldn't be doing in any browser anyway. I'm surprised it renders anywhere. It's horrible semantics and it'd never validate.